# How to add an extra shipping cost to the total price of my shopping cart in ruby ​on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, shopping-cart, shipping-method

Apparently everything on my page is "fine" but I would like to make the following modifications, I hope you can help me .
I would like the user to select the National shipping option of the form check that I have below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9giSo.png), add +150 to the Total price of the cart and when they select Personal delivery only CDMX
only the total price of the products is displayed. I had thought and even tried with an if but did not know how to implement it.

**This is my shopping_cart.rb class from app / models**

```
class ShoppingCart < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :in_shopping_carts
    has_many :products, through: :in_shopping_carts
    enum status: {payed: 1, default: 0}

    
    def total
        products.sum(:pricing)
    end
    
end
```

**This is my show.haml class from app / views / shopping_carts**

```
%h1.mb-3.text-align:center.text-center Mi carrito
.form-check
    %p Selecciona tu tipo de envio:
    %input#exampleRadios1.form-check-input{checked: "checked", name: "exampleRadios", type: "radio", value: "option1"}/
    %label.form-check-label{for: "exampleRadios1"}
    Entrega personal solo CDMX
.form-check
    %input#exampleRadios2.form-check-input{name: "exampleRadios", type: "radio", value: "option2"}/
    %label.form-check-label{for: "exampleRadios2"}
    Envio nacional

.card.large-padding 
    %table.table.table-striped.table-hover.small#table_shopping_cart
        %thead
            %td Producto
            %td Costo
            %td Acciones
        %tbody
            -@shopping_cart.in_shopping_carts.each do |i_sh|
                -product = i_sh.product
                %tr{id: "#{product.id}"}
                    %td= product.name
                    %td= product.pricing
                    %td= link_to "Eliminar",i_sh,method: :delete
    .top-space.large-padding.text-center#payment_form
        %p.medium
            %strong
                Total: $
                =@shopping_cart.total
```

And **This is my shopping_carts_controller.rb class from app / controllers**

```
class ShoppingCartsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        if @shopping_cart.payed?
            render "shopping_carts/complete"
            return
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to tell the controller that either option was selected.

The basic way to do this is for the user to press a button after they select the radio to submit to a controller method. This controller method will tell your shopping cart if it becomes either a National Delivery or a Personal Pickup type.

Roughly something like:

```
# view
form_tag change_delivery_method_path(@shopping_cart)
  label
    Personal
    radio_button_tag "delivery_method", "personal"
  label
    National
    radio_button_tag "delivery_method", "national"
  submit_button_tag

# controller
def change_delivery_method
  shopping_cart = ShoppingCart.find(params[:shopping_cart_id])
  shopping_cart.update(delivery_method: params[:delivery_method])
end
```

From there, you can modify the total accordingly.

```
class ShoppingCart < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :in_shopping_carts
    has_many :products, through: :in_shopping_carts
    enum status: {payed: 1, default: 0}
    enum delivery_method: { personal: 0, national: 1 }
    
    def total
        products.sum(:pricing) + delivery_fee
    end

    def delivery_fee
        return 150 if national?
        return 0 if personal?
    end
end
```

The next level would be converting the form submit into AJAX.

Comment: I have edited my comment, could you tell me if even with what I update your answer would work?

Comment: Hi @VictordeGallegos, the view & controller code above is not guaranteed to work as written. It is more of to show you the rough idea about it. You'll have to write routing and all the other extra implementation details.